# jQuery lazy load of element's object or reload it on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it's possible to have only one creation of jQuery object from element query , even when the element is not available yet, and let's say will be added later by other function on page, reload the object to find this element on page?

What I was trying to do for tests is:

```
<script>
    var crab = $('#crab');
</script>
<div id="crab">Hello Crab</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    crab.load();
    console.log( crab.html() );
</script>
```

This, of course, still returns undefined.
I want to do it because PHPStorm complains about duplicate jQuery selectors in my functions, because something when this element exists, I have to grab it, do something and delete it, then when it's recreated, I have to get it again in the same function.

Possible? Or just leave 2 queries on the same element when necessary?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that contains these two queries?